# Unable to load the package 'enthought.mayavi.mlab'

Tags: python, mayavi

I'm trying to load the package enthought.mayavi.mlab in python's spider enviorment:

```
import enthought.mayavi.mlab as mlb
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 487, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Eytan\Desktop\Mah\PyBrainTraining.py", line 2, in <module>
    import enthought.mayavi.mlab as mlb
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthought\mayavi\mlab.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mayavi.mlab import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 27, in <module>
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 25, in <module>
    from engine_manager import get_engine
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from mayavi.preferences.api import preference_manager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\preferences\api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from preference_manager import preference_manager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\preferences\preference_manager.py", line 29, in <module>
    from traitsui.api import View, Group, Item
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\api.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .editors.api import (ArrayEditor, BooleanEditor, ButtonEditor,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .api import (toolkit, ArrayEditor, BooleanEditor, ButtonEditor,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .code_editor import CodeEditor
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\code_editor.py", line 36, in <module>
    class ToolkitEditorFactory ( EditorFactory ):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\code_editor.py", line 48, in ToolkitEditorFactory
    mark_color = Color( 0xECE9D8 )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\traits.py", line 487, in __call__
    return self.maker_function( *args, **metadata )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\traits.py", line 1183, in Color
    return ColorTrait( *args, **metadata )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\toolkit_traits.py", line 7, in ColorTrait
    return toolkit().color_trait( *args, **traits )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\toolkit.py", line 109, in toolkit
    _toolkit = _import_toolkit(ETSConfig.toolkit)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\toolkit.py", line 51, in _import_toolkit
    return __import__( name, globals=globals(), level=1 ).toolkit
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\qt4\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pyface.qt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyface\qt\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    prepare_pyqt4()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyface\qt\__init__.py", line 17, in prepare_pyqt4
    sip.setapi('QString', 2)
ValueError: API 'QString' has already been set to version 1
```

anyone knows how to fix it?
Edit: If it will help, I see think that the problem is explained in the last column:

```
ValueError: API 'QString' has already been set to version 1
```

Edit: I tried changing API selection for QString and QVariant objects to Api #1,#2. didn't help.
Tried either to set the "Ignore API change errors" to true, didn't help.
Tried EST_TOOLKIT from 'qt4' to 'wx'.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because spider itself uses the QT library and has already initialized it. 
According to this http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html you could use PySide instead of PyQt4 (but i don't know if that's a configuation option or a fallback).

Comment: the installation requirements for spider says it needs PyQt4 OR PySide, so presumably you could get it to use PySide and that way leave PyQt4 uninitialized, so avoiding the double initialization problem.